# Reduce to only row totalRevenue and rename the colunmn names in years using yahoo finance and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I try to scrape the yearly total revenues from yahoo finance using pandas and yahoo_fin by using the following code:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM')

income_statements_yearly= [] #All numbers in thousands

for ticker in tickers:    
    income_statement = si.get_income_statement(ticker, yearly=True)    
    years = income_statement.columns
    income_statement.insert(loc=0, column='Ticker', value=ticker)
    for i in range(4):       
        #print(years[i].year)        
        income_statement.rename(columns = {years[i]:years[i].year}, inplace = True)
    income_statements_yearly.append(income_statement)
income_statements_yearly = pd.concat(income_statements_yearly)
income_statements_yearly
```

The result I get looks like:

[image]

[image]

I would like to create on that basis another dataframe revenues and reduce the dataframe to only the row totalRevenue instead of getting all rows and at the same time I would love to rename the columns 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018 to revenues_2021, revenues_2020, revenues_2019, revenues_2018.

The result shall look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM'],
                   'revenues_2021': [365817000000, 168088000000, 57351000000],
                   'revenues_2020': [274515000000, 143015000000, 55179000000],
                   'revenues_2019': [260174000000, 125843000000, 57714000000],
                   'revenues_2018': [265595000000, 110360000000, 79591000000]})
```

How can I solve this in an easy and fast way?

Ty for your help in advance.

Comment: add the output you want

Comment: @vigneshkanakavalli Ty, I've added the output as a dataframe.

Comment: Remove one indent for the line `income_statements_yearly.append(income_statement)`. You need to append the data frame only after changing all column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CODE**

```
revenues = income_statements_yearly.loc["totalRevenue"].reset_index(drop=True)
revenues.columns = ["Ticker"] + ["revenues_" + str(col) for col in revenues.columns if col != "Ticker"]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
            Ticker revenues_2021 revenues_2020 revenues_2019 revenues_2018
0            AAPL  365817000000  274515000000  260174000000  265595000000
1            MSFT  168088000000  143015000000  125843000000  110360000000
2             IBM   57351000000   55179000000   57714000000   79591000000
```

Comment: Thank you, the column name change works fine, but the 
sales amounts are not correct, because all rows are summed up, but only the row totalRevenue is relevant, the other rows must be deleted.

Comment: Where is the column totalRevenue in the dataframe? I cannot find totalRevenue any where?

Comment: it is part of income_statements_yearly, see the screenshot I ve posted at the beginning. If u use my code, u can produce the dataframe income_statements_yearly and c the row. In the output example u c the revenue_2021 is for AAPL 365817000000, In your example it is 1655674000000.

Comment: No what I am asking is, In the screenshot you posted there is no totalRevenue. Are you taking about netIncome or grossProfit?

Comment: Sorry, the dataframe was too long so I ve posted only a snippet, but I have now added another picture. Can u c it?

Comment: please be careful from next time. check it now!

Comment: Thanks now it looks almost perfect, the revenue values for each year r correct, but I have four times the same row for each ticker so a total of 12 where four times each is the same.

Comment: I already mentioned it. You are using an extra indentation in your code. Check the comment under your question

Comment: Thanks, u r right, the line "income_statements_yearly.append(income_statement)" was indented in the second for loop, if I make it valid for the first one it works perfectly!

Comment: Pls allow me a last question. revenues.columns = ["revenues_" + str(col) for col in revenues.columns] makes all columns named with a prefix "revenues_" but the first coumn Ticker shall not renamed to "revenues_Ticker". The name shall remain Ticker, how can I fix this? TY sooo much!

Comment: Ty, but unfortunately I get an error: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 4 elements"

Comment: Check it now. I didn't focus on the error earlier

Comment: TY sooooooooooo much, u r the best, I cant tell u how much I appreciate it. U helped me soo much ty!!!!